# Can't point shell at local spring cloud data flow server?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am learning how to use Spring Cloud Data Flow. A lot of the tutorials make use of the shell so I am trying to get that set up. I am able to start the shell but I get server unknown.  I have been trying to point the shell at my local running instance of the server (dataflow config server http://localhost:9393)but I keep getting the errors listed below. I am able to navigate to my server and run applications so I know that it is working on port 9393, not sure why the shell can not see it. I am running version 1.0.0.M3 for the shell.

I have tried the following.

server-unknown:>dataflow config server http://localhost:9393

Unable to contact Data Flow Server at 'http://localhost:9393': 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Deployments relation is required'.

server-unknown:>dataflow config server 'http://localhost:9393'

Unable to contact Data Flow Server at 'http://localhost:9393':

'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Deployments relation is required'.

server-unknown:>dataflow config server http://localhost:9393

Unable to contact Data Flow Server at 'http://localhost:9393': 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Deployments relation is required'.

server-unknown:>dataflow config server --uri http://localhost:9393

Unable to contact Data Flow Server at 'http://localhost:9393': 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Deployments relation is required'.

server-unknown:>dataflow config server http://localhost:9393/

Unable to contact Data Flow Server at 'http://localhost:9393/': 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Deployments relation is required'.

server-unknown:>dataflow config server \http://localhost:9393/

Unable to contact Data Flow Server at '\http://localhost:9393/': 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: \http://localhost:9393/'.
server-unknown:>dataflow config server https://localhost:9393/

Unable to contact Data Flow Server at 'https://localhost:9393/': 'org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://localhost:9393/": Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?'.
server-unknown:>dataflow config server --uri  http://localhost:9393/   --skip-ssl-validation true
Option 'skip-ssl-validation' is not available for this command. Use tab assist or the "help" command to see the legal options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1.0.0 M3 version is at least 2yrs old.

Please upgrade to the latest GA release for bot SCDF and the Shell applications. You can get the latest release coordinates for the both from the [getting-started](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/local/manual/) guide.